# Neo4j - Unmanaged extensions with SDN - InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not resolve dependency of type:javax.transaction.TransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I followed example from: https://inserpio.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/extending-the-neo4j-server-with-spring-data-neo4j/

Created 1 Repo, 1 Controller (with get and put rest endpoints. get /test/get/{name} uses 'name' property to get the node, put /test/create is just a test endpoint for now that always should create same node which later on i want to get...) and 1 Domain class.. Together with the PluginInitializer, that exposed Neo4jTemplate and my custom repo.

My app-context:

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:spring-configured />

<context:component-scan base-package="uk.co.neo4j.extension.tvshow">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<neo4j:config base-package="uk.co.neo4j.extension.tvshow.domain" graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />
<neo4j:repositories base-package="uk.co.neo4j.extension.tvshow.repository" />

<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" />
```

Pom file dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-configuration.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.validation.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.transaction.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Followed by maven-compiler-plugin to copy all dependant jar files into lib folder. Add PluginInit fqp to PluginLifecycle file, as well as added package to neo4j server config:
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=uk.co.neo4j.extension.tvshow=/tv

I copied my jar file + all dependant jar files into neo4j server plugin folder, started it successfully:

```
**2015-03-22 21:49:37.411+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.m.ThirdPartyJAXRSModule]: Mounted unmanaged extension [uk.co.neo4j.extension.tvshow] at [/tv]**
2015-03-22 21:49:37.535+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.w.Jetty9WebServer]: Mounting static content at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
2015-03-22 21:49:37.625+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.w.Jetty9WebServer]: Mounting static content at [/browser] from [browser]
2015-03-22 21:49:40.361+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer]: Server started on: http://localhost:7474/
2015-03-22 21:49:40.361+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer]: Remote interface ready and available at [http://localhost:7474/]
2015-03-22 21:49:40.361+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- SERVER STARTED END ---
```

BUT! When I try to use it via rest, i.e. :PUT /tv/test/create OR :GET /tv/test/get/testnode i always get:

```
Error: 500 - Internal Server Error
```

In logs I found this, and it happens for both get and put:

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not resolve dependency of type:javax.transaction.TransactionManager; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve dependency of type:javax.transaction.TransactionManager
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(Neo4jExceptionTranslator.java:48)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.save(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.save(Unknown Source)
    at uk.co.neo4j.extension.tvshow.rest.TestController.createTestNode(TestController.java:64)
...
```

So basically, whenever any operation is done against my repository:

```
testRepository.getTestNodeByName(name);
testRepository.save(testNode);
```

It treats it as transaction and the Transaction Manager is not found... From the doc's of SDN I've read that neo4jTransactionManager bean is already configured as part of Neo4jConfiguration, and yes I've checked - it is already there:

```
@Bean(name = {"neo4jTransactionManager","transactionManager"})
    @Qualifier("neo4jTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager neo4jTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new JtaTransactionManagerFactoryBean(getGraphDatabaseService()).getObject();
    }
```

So what am I missing? :(

Comment: Using these dependency versions:    


                                                <spring-data-neo4j.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>
        <neo4j.version>2.2.0-RC01</neo4j.version>
        <commons-configuration.version>1.10</commons-configuration.version>
        <javax.validation.version>1.0.0.GA</javax.validation.version>
        <javax.transaction.version>1.1</javax.transaction.version>